# Why does this ajax request replace all my comments with the newly submitted comment?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have this form which requests a JS call when a comment is submitted:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@video, @video.comments.new], :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :comment_title, :collection => @video.comment_titles, :label => "Comment Title:", :include_blank => false %>
  <%= f.input :body, :label => false, :placeholder => "Post a comment." %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :value => "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

It calls this create action in the comments controller:

```
def create
  @comment = @video.comments.new(params[:comment].merge({:user_id => current_user.id}))
  if @comment.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back, :alert => "Unable to add comment." }
      format.js { render 'fail_create.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

which renders this create.js.erb file:

```
$(".comment_content").html('<%= escape_javascript(render(@comment)) %>');
$(".comment_form")[0].reset();
```

The above create.js.erb file renders the comment partial into this file:

```
<% comment_title.comments.each do |comment| %>
     <div class="comment_content">
        <%= render comment %>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

Why are all of my comments being replaced by the newly submitted comment in this AJAX request?

Here's my comment partial:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.profile.photo.url(:tiny)), profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => "comment_image" %>
<div class="textual_comment_content">
    <div class="comment_text">
        <span class="name_link">
            <%= link_to "#{comment.user.name}", profile_path(comment.user.profile), :class => "normal" %>
        </span>
        <%= comment.body.gsub("'",'&apos;').html_safe %>
    </div>
    <span class="comment_footer">
        <ul>
            <li class="list_style"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</li>
            <% unless current_user != comment.user %>
            <li><%= link_to "Delete", video_comment_path(:video_id => @video, :id => comment), :method => :delete, :class => "normal" %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
     </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: try using `append()` / `prepend()` instead of `html()` ?

Comment: just doing just that doesn't work... but maybe if some other things are changed as well...

Comment: What do you mean by, it doesn't work?

Comment: use either firebug or similar to see whats being returned from the ajax call... this should point more clearly to the problem... what Khez suggested should work (using html() is just asking to replace everything)

Comment: using append() messes up the layout

Comment: you have to append to parent of first comment, `$(".comment_content:first").parent().append('<%= escape_javascript(render(@comment)) %>');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first You need to move wrapping div from first code to the partial:

```
<div class="comment_content">
</div>
```

then just insert html before/after first/last element:

```
$(".comment_content:first").before('<%= escape_javascript(render(@comment)) %>');
$(".comment_content:last").after('<%= escape_javascript(render(@comment)) %>');
```

Comment: this actually gets the visual layout wrong. I'm posting my comment partial because you might need that info.

Comment: Also it would help to know that I not only loop through comments, but I also loop through the comment titles first. Essentially it's a loop within a loop so I have all the comments that belong to its respective comment title appear below it, and each column belongs to a different column title

Comment: I accepted your answer because I didn't provide enough information and your answer was essentially correct. I figured it out in my app though.