# How can I do this with Rails 3 Jquery? (Complex Forms Part 2)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In this episode Ryan loads up child elements dynamically.  I need to do the same via Rails 3 and Jquery.

Example:

Month

- Event
- Event

+Add Event

Also need to be able to delete events.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Best,
Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem is based on the idea behind nested form examples, you should check out: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Answer (score 0):

You questions seams to be covered by this question [Why does this ajax request replace all my comments with the newly submitted comment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585336/why-does-this-ajax-request-replace-all-my-comments-with-the-newly-submitted-comme)

Answer (score 0):

basically...

you add

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

to your Gemfile, then run bundler

```
bundle install
```

and execute the jquery installer

```
rails g jquery:install
```

to install/replace the necessary javascript-files in order to have your app use jquery instead of prototype

then you can pretty much do the same that Ryan does in his railscast... I'd guess you just might have to twitch and tweak the code a little so it fits your needs